# Example for animating a scatter plot in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of about 1000 points that I'd like to scatter plot with d3js. I'd like about 10 points to appear every .1 seconds. Is there a simple example of this somewhere? The d3js tutorials are detailed, but I can't seem to find one for this case.

Comment: what have you done so far??

Answer (score 1):

- http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-scatterplot/ and http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2595950 ->this example gives you a basic idea of how to draw a scatter plot!!!
- http://swizec.com/blog/quick-scatterplot-tutorial-for-d3-js/swizec/5337 -->Tutorial

  You need to understand these first!!!
- **DEMO FIDDLE for your animation in scatterplot-**-->http://jsfiddle.net/eaGhB/3/

  ```
       var w = 960,h = 500,nodes = [];

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h);

      var force = d3.layout.force()
          .charge(-300)
          .size([w, h])
          .nodes(nodes)
          .on("tick", tick)
          .start();

      function tick() {
          svg.selectAll("circle")
              .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });

      }

      var interval = setInterval(function () {
          var d = {
              x: w / 2 + 2 * Math.random()-1 ,
              y: h / 2 + 2 * Math.random() - 1
          };

          svg.append("svg:circle")
              .data([d])
              .attr("r", 10)
            .transition()
              .ease(Math.sqrt)
                 .style("stroke", "gray")
       .style("fill", "red")
       .attr("r", 10);

          if (nodes.push(d) > 20) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              d3.selectAll('circle').on("mouseover", animate).on("mouseout", function () {
                  d3.select(this).transition()
                      .duration(100)
              .attr("r", 40);
                  d3.selectAll('circle').style("fill", "black");
              });
          }
          force.stop()
          force.start();
      }, 200);


      function animate() {
          d3.select(this).transition()
              .duration(300)
              .attr("r", 20);


          d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");
          var sel = d3.select(this);
          sel.moveToFront();
      };
      d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function () {
          return this.each(function () {
              this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
          });
      };
  ```

  - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery-->these are many example that you can refer too.